# Portable persistance queue -> uploader

Tags: java, objective-c, mobile, architecture

I need to implement a disk-backed queue which can accept real-time profiling data from multiple threads and then upload that data over potentially faulty transports. Initially targeted at Java but long-term we will need to use the same mechanism in Objective-C, Flash, JavaScript. Targeted at android Java as well as desktop.

This will be contained within a single process, so an MQ solution is probably out. Performance is a point of significant consideration, meaning we'd trade some reliability for performance.

[image: Architecture Diagram]

I'm curious about two things:

1. Given the above architecture, is there any available technology that'll completely or partially solve this problem?
2. Given the goal of eventually re-implementing or ideally re-using this mechanism in different platforms, is there any way to build this in a way that can be easily used in say both Objective-C & Android Java?
3. How's this architecture look?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to keep limited amount of data (circular log), and able to reserve fixed amount of persistent memory for it, then most effective solution is [memory-mapped buffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html). Persister is simply a cache of several buffers, serving both profiling queue and uploader.

When reimplementing it on other platforms, chances are that the platform has no mapping facility. In this case, buffers can be read and written directly. This can be less efficient than mapping to memory, but still no less efficient than other solutions (e.g. embedded database).

As for the architecture, the picture does not reflect the situation when data is read from persister (or else what for is persister needed?). Then, profiling queue actually embrace the whole data (including persistent), and what is named as profiling queue is the buffers in main memory, they can be not contiguous, so better name is buffer cache than queue.

Comment: This is a good point regarding the persister. I omitted this intentionally, but perhaps I should have clarified. I intended that the persister would be read on start-up to pull in any saved but not uploaded events.

Very awesome I didn't know that android supported this but it does - http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html